# Really though, why can't a equilibrium manifest in a open system?

Tags: equilibrium

**What my teacher said today:** "Equilibrium is not attainable in an open system because then there the concentrations of the species in the system are undergoing continuous change, thus the reverse and forward rates can never be equal"

**Thought Experiment that contradicts my teacher:**
However, consider the tank with an equal-sized hole at the bottom and top at which water is being added in at the same rate. The macroscopic amount of water in the tank is constant and the system is open. But it is an equilibirum!

So is my teacher wrong or what?

Comment: That is not an equilibrium, but a steady state. There would be no flow at equilibrium.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_state Once the water is gone it is gone. That's irreversible, therefore not equilibrium.

Comment: But, IMHO, if an open system was a part of a bigger, closed system and if this closed system was in equilibrium, I suppose we could say the open system as its part is in equilibrium too. But it would be rather very specific case.

Comment: A (lossless) confined current in a superconductor might be considered an equilibrium system.

Comment: [Semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics)

Comment: @BuckThorn Would not it be rather a frozen non-equilibrium state? And it would be a closed system.

Comment: @Poutnik I refer to the electrons flowing in the conductor. The example is not perfect as there are surely radiative losses (if not resistive, for a perfect conductor). A cross-section would be an open system.

Comment: @Poutnik Actually, ideally there might not even be radiative losses: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387498/a-question-related-to-energy-losses-in-superconductors. Scratch that statement about non-thermal electrons.

Comment: Listen to and discuss this with your teacher.